# How to make Unsigned right shift (>>>) in rust?

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

How to make Unsigned right shift (>>>) in rust? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unsigned_right_shift

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. There is no answer in the linked question.

Answer (score 2):

For positive numbers you can just use the shift operator `>>`.

For negative numbers however, I'm going to assume you're dealing with an `i32`. The behavior in the docs you linked shifts the binary representation of a negative number to the right. Therefore we first need to reinterpret the negative integer as an unsigned integer. The safest way of doing it would be with the use of `to_be_bytes` and `from_be_bytes`.

```
fn main() {
    let a: u32 = 5;
    let b: u32 = 2;
    let c: i32 = -5;

    let c_as_u32: u32 = {
        let bytes = c.to_be_bytes();
        u32::from_be_bytes(bytes)
    };

    let x = a >> b;
    let y = c_as_u32 >> b;
    
    println!("x = {}", x); // x = 1
    println!("y = {}", y); // x = 1073741822
}
```

Comment: It is better to use [to_ne_bytes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.to_ne_bytes) because this doesn't require any rearranging of bytes during this transform. Also, almost all modern CPUs are little-endian so it would always be less optimal than le_bytes. ne_bytes is always good at any platform.

Comment: What's wrong with simply using `c as u32`? I was under the impression that this has well-defined behaviour in Rust.

Comment: [The reference states](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#numeric-cast): "Casting between two integers of the same size (e.g. i32 -> u32) is a no-op (Rust uses 2's complement for negative values of fixed integers)", so `((c as u32) >> b) as i32` should do the trick.